# setText to an editText located in LoginActivity.java, from onAuthenticationSuceeded() method on FingerprintHandler.java

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

setText to an editText located in LoginActivity.java, from onAuthenticationSuceeded() method on FingerprintHandler.java

LoginActivity.java is connected with an xml file named activity_login.xml and has the editText username and password. When user's fingerprint is recognised, I need to setText for username and password however the onAuthenticationSuceeded() is located in FingerprintHandler.java which is not connected to any xml file.

The code below in FingerprintHandler.java won't work, clearly because the username and password editTexts aren't clearly connected to the FingerprintHandler.java page except for

```
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
username.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
password.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
}
```

The only part where LoginActivity.java is connected to FingerprintHandler.java is via this code in LoginActivity:

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        fingerprintHandler.startAuth(fingerprintManager, null);
```

Any guidance appreciated thank you.

Comment: Do you have your activity context inside handler class

Comment: I don't think so, Can you guide me on how I add the context in the handler class?

Answer (score 1):

first u get the value and save it in string and set the string in edittext as settext

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to setText on an editText in an xml file called activity_login.xml which is connected to LoginActivity.java.

Comment: first u get the value and save it in string and set the string in edittext as settext

Answer (score 0):

You have to use interface to tell the activity that fingerprint is authenticated successfully and in your activity, you can show the text in edit text.

1) First, create an interface in FingerPrintHandler.java

```
public interface FingeprintAuthenticationListener {
void onAuthenticationSucceeded();
}
```

2) implement this interface in your activity.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FingeprintAuthenticationListener

@override 
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded() {
username.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
password.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
}
```

3) pass the interface reference to the FingerPrintHandler.java class

```
FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler = new FingerprintHandler(this, this);
```

4) in your FingerPrintHandler.java class save the interface reference and call the interface method in onAuthenticationSucceeded method.

```
private FingeprintAuthenticationListener listener;
public FingerprintHandler(Context context, FingeprintAuthenticationListener listener) {
this.context = context;
this.listener = listener;
}
```

and in your onAuthenticationSucceeded method call the interface method.

```
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
listener.onAuthenticationSucceeded();
}
```

Comment: Passing Activity Context to Handler results in memory leaks.

Comment: @ankuranurag2 yes it can if the app supports orientation change

Comment: FingerPrintHandler class needs the interface reference to communicate with the activity

Comment: We use `WeakReference` to handle such scenarios.

Comment: after sending the result setting the `listener=null` will prevent memory leak